# Client templating in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My controller fills in $scope.gridData with json related to a student's info (StudentName and FavoriteDay).

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Format</b></td>
                <td><b>Day of Month</b></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in gridData">
                <td>{{i.StudentName}}</td>
                <td>{{i.FavoriteDay}}</td> <--
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

The FavoriteDay value I get from SQL is number 1 through 7. But I would like to replace them with actual days like Monday, Tuesday.. So I have function like this

```
 function changeToDay(day) {
  if (day == '1') return 'Monday'
  if (day == '2') return 'Tuesday'
  ...
  }
```

And replaced the html with this

```
  <td> {{changeToDay(i.Favorite)}} </td>
```

But this doesnt seem to work.

Please suggest the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a scoped function but Angular has an abstraction for this called **filters**.

```
app.filter('day', function() {
  var text = ['Sunday', 'Monday', ...];
  return function(day) {
    return text[day];
  };
});
```

then you can use it **globally** in your application:

```
<td> {{ i.Favorite | day }} </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not in the scope you can remove all your ifs statements and do this like that:

```
var days = ['sunday','monday']....;

$scope.changeToDay = function(day) {
  return days[day];
}

<td> {{changeToDay(i.Favorite)}} </td>
```

Or if for some reason the array structure does not make sense to your structure you can write it like you want.